# C macro containing static variables as conditional

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am wondering if it is possible in plain C (*C99*) to have a macro which contains static variables which can be used inside conditional expressions.

I came up with the following (as a function):

```
char EDGE(unsigned long x)
{
    static char up = 0;
    static unsigned long v;
    if (up && v != x) {
        v = x;
        return 1;
    } else {
        v = x;
        up = 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

which is exactly what I want, except that it only works once (one misses the cached value on invoking this **function** with another variable).

So I thought about macros in C and the fact, that if this would work I got a variable cache for free, without having to manage anything. Is this even possible using plain old C?

**Note:** I want to have a simple to use edge detection 'function' which might be simply invoked inside an *if*-statement.

Comment: Can't you maintain a table keyed by the pointers to such variables?

Comment: Could you please show an example of how you'd like to use the desired macro in different contexts and explain why the function cannot do the job?

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, but I thought using macros I can avoid this.

Comment: That would be a bit like avoiding cleaning your house by setting fire to it.

Comment: @StephanLechner I explained right underneath the code. To be more precise, the above function only works with one variable, because on every subsequent call i lose the old variable value. I need to call this function repeadly for any use. Sample usage: `while (1) { if (EDGE(p) run(); }`

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Bathsheba: well, to me it's completely unclear what the function supposed to do with "another variable"... there is nothing in the signature that allows that.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath That's why I added the note, but I got your point.

Comment: Another option would be to convert `x` to a `struct` that contains all the extra payload. Of course if the current answer is accepted then I have misread the question.

Comment: Why not get rid of the statics and give your edge function/macro a second parameter? statics are bad for cache locality and reentrancy.

Comment: @PSkocik Sorry, but I could not follow. How should this solve the task? I need to remember the value of last invocation, that's why the statics in the function.

Comment: @maxik You can create a state variable on the stack and pass a pointer to that state variable along with the x integer. That should be a much more optimal solution than one relying on statics.

Comment: @maxik Something like. `static inline bool edge(ulong *last_p, ulong curr) { bool r = *last_p != curr; *last_p = curr; return r; }`. Simple and performant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you'll need two macros.  The first is used to set up an edge function for a particular variable, while the second is used to call the relevant function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEF_EDGE(var) static char edge##var(unsigned long var) \
{ \
    static char up = 0; \
    static unsigned long v = 0; \
    if (up && v != var) { \
        v = var; \
        return 1; \
    } else { \
        v = var; \
        up = 1; \
        return 0; \
    } \
}

#define EDGE(var) edge##var(var)

DEF_EDGE(x)
DEF_EDGE(y)

int main()
{
    unsigned long x = 2, y = 3;
    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    x=3;
    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    y=4;
    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    x=1; y=2;
    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x=2, y=3 edge(x)=0, edge(y)=0
x=2, y=3 edge(x)=0, edge(y)=0
x=3, y=3 edge(x)=1, edge(y)=0
x=3, y=3 edge(x)=0, edge(y)=0
x=3, y=4 edge(x)=0, edge(y)=1
x=3, y=4 edge(x)=0, edge(y)=0
x=1, y=2 edge(x)=1, edge(y)=1
x=1, y=2 edge(x)=0, edge(y)=0
```

In each of these macros, `##` is the concatenation operator.  This combines two tokens into one.

When you use the first macro at file scope as:

```
DEF_EDGE(y)
```

This expands into:

```
static char edgey(unsigned long var)
{
    static char up = 0;
    static unsigned long v = 0;
    if (up && v != var) {
        v = var;
        return 1;
    } else {
        v = var;
        up = 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now you have a function that can check for an edge condition for `y`.

Then when you use the second macro:

```
EDGE(y)
```

This expands to:

```
edgey(y)
```

Note that for this to work, each variable you set up an EDGE function for has to have a unique name, regardless of scope.

EDIT:

Here's another way to do this that doesn't have scoping issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char edge(unsigned long var, unsigned long *v)
{
    if (*v != var) {
        *v = var;
        return 1;
    } else {
        *v = var;
        return 0;
    }
}

#define EDGE(var) edge(var, &var##_last)

#define SET_EDGE(var) \
    unsigned long var##_last = var;

int main()
{
    unsigned long x = 2, y = 3;
    SET_EDGE(x);
    SET_EDGE(y);

    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    x=3;
    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    y=4;
    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    x=1; y=2;
    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    printf("x=%lu, y=%lu edge(x)=%d, edge(y)=%d\n", x, y, EDGE(x), EDGE(y));
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, you call the `SET_EDGE` macro just after the relevant variable is defined.  This creates another variable with `_last` appended to the name, keeping track of the prior value.  The address of this state variable is then passed to the `edge` function when you use the `EDGE` mecro.

Comment: For anyone who needs reference (like me) to understand this, look here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation .

Comment: Note that one might bypass the unique name restriction by introducing a scope parameter.

Comment: @maxik See my edit which should address the scoping issue.

Comment: For anyone reading to note: the second solution does not work with global variables (initialization issue) but one may introduce another macro like `#define SET_EDGE_G(var,val) \ unsigned long var##_last = val;` and call it like `SET_EDGE_G(gVar, 0)` which works.